# escaped xml with cdata that has also has both escaped data value and tags

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am receiving xml data from a web service that returns all the data as one escaped xml string. however for whatever reason, part of the xml is enclosed within a cdata tag. The escape xml within the cdata will often contain escaped xml character as well. example:

```
&lt;root&gt;
  &lt;importData&gt;dat&lt;/importData&gt;
  &lt;Response&gt;
   <![CDATA[&lt;SecondRoot&gt;
   &lt;Data&gt;123&lt;/Data&gt;
   &lt;DataEscapedCharacterIncluded&gt; 3 &gt; 1&lt;/DataEscapedCharacterIncluded&gt;
   &lt;/SecondRoot&gt;]]>
  &lt;/Response&gt;
&lt;/root&gt;
```

I need to transform both the xml inside and out of the cdata section into another xml format with xsl, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get this into a usable xml form with either c# or xsl so I can do the xsl transform into a different format. I would like it look like below:

```
  <root>
     <importData>dat</importData>
     <Response>
      <SecondRoot>
       <Data>123</Data>
       <DataEscapedCharacterIncluded> 3 &gt; 1</DataEscapedCharacterIncluded>
      </SecondRoot>
     </Response>
  <root>
```

Comment: perhaps you can convert your xml to string and use replace method in c# to remove <![CDATA[ and ]]>, then it should become a valid xml syntax

Comment: Are you sure the entire response is escaped at the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you show may not be properly escaped. If you unescape it, it may yield not well-formed XML. Consider this line:

```
&lt;DataEscapedCharacterIncluded&gt; 3 &gt; 1&lt;/DataEscapedCharacterIncluded&gt;
```

If you unescape it, it will become this:

```
<DataEscapedCharacterIncluded> 3 > 1</DataEscapedCharacterIncluded>
```

This is still valid (a greater-than does not need to be escaped), but I assume that you'll also have `&lt;` in there somewhere, which *must* be escaped. If it is doubly escaped you should be fine.

To transform this there are several things you can do:

- With XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, transform it in two passes, one that does the
  unescaping with `disable-output-escaping` set to `yes`, and another
  one to do the actual transformation.
- Use an extension function that takes a string and returns a node set.
- With XSLT 3.0, use the new function [`fn:parse-xml`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) or
  [`fn:parse-xml-fragment`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml-fragment), which can take XML-as-a-string as
  input.
- If your entire source is escaped, as it looks like, [feed it unescaped to 
  the XSLT processor as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203485/built-in-net-function-for-unescaping-characters-in-xml-stream). This will also take care of 
  the escaped CDATA (but that part will remain escaped, see below).

What is not entirely clear from your post is whether it is doubly escaped. I.e., if your data looks like this:

```
<elem><![CDATA[<root>bla</root>]]></elem>
```

it is singly escaped. If it looks like this:

```
<elem><![CDATA[&lt;root&gt;bla&lt;/root&gt;]]></elem>
```

it is doubly escaped. In the latter case, you will need to do an extra unescape cycle before you can process it.