# Error using XElement.Parse

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have a XML configuration for Query CAML:

```
<add key="QueryList" value="&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='Cargar_x0020_Optimyth'/&gt;&lt;Value Type='Boolean'&gt;1&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;" />
<add key="PaginacionList" value="10" />
<add key="QueryOptions" value="&lt;IncludeMandatoryColumns&gt;FALSE&lt;/IncludeMandatoryColumns&gt;&lt;Paging ListItemCollectionPositionNext=''/&gt;" />
```

Now, I want do this:

```
    XElement ndQuery = XElement.Parse(Configuracion.QueryList);
    XElement ndViewFields = XElement.Parse(Configuracion.ViewFields);
    XElement ndQueryOptions = XElement.Parse(Configuracion.QueryOptions);
```

but I get an error.

I try this using `XmlElement` and its working:

```
    XmlElement ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuracion.QueryList))
    {
        ndQuery.InnerXml = Configuracion.QueryList;
    }
    XmlElement ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuracion.ViewFields))
    {
        ndViewFields.InnerXml = Configuracion.ViewFields;
    }
    XmlElement ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuracion.QueryOptions))
    {
        ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = Configuracion.QueryOptions;
    }

    XElement ndQuery = XElement.Parse(ndQuery2.OuterXml);
    XElement ndViewFields = XElement.Parse(ndViewFields2.OuterXml);
    XElement ndQueryOptions = XElement.Parse(ndQueryOptions2.OuterXml);
```

I want avoid use `XmlElement`, and only `XElement`.

Any solution about it?

Comment: What's the error? Which line is producing the error?

Comment: @xanatos the value if for **key="QueryList"** in app.config.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML in the QueryOptions setting isn't an element. It's two sibling elements. You need one surrounding them, which in this case would be `<QueryOptions>`:

```
<add key="QueryOptions" 
 value="&lt;QueryOptions&gt;&lt;IncludeMandatoryColumns&gt;FALSE&lt;/IncludeMandatoryColumns&gt;&lt;Paging ListItemCollectionPositionNext=''/&gt;&lt;/QueryOptions&gt;" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Quite complex because you have an Xml fragment (multiple root nodes) in `Configuracion.QueryOptions`. The XLinq doesn't have direct methods to handle it... Based on [Fragmented XML string parsing with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114789/fragmented-xml-string-parsing-with-linq), you could

```
public static IEnumerable<XNode> ParseXml(string xml)
{
    // Note the added escaping
    // You can replace it with WebUtility.HtmlDecode
    // They are defined in different assemblies
    xml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xml);

    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
        IgnoreWhitespace = true
    };

    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
    {
        xmlReader.MoveToContent();
        while (xmlReader.ReadState != ReadState.EndOfFile)
        {
            yield return XNode.ReadFrom(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
XElement ndQuery = new XElement("Query", ParseXml(Configuracion.QueryList));
XElement ndViewFields = new XElement("ViewFields", ParseXml(Configuracion.ViewFields));
XElement ndQueryOptions = new XElement("QueryOptions", ParseXml(Configuracion.QueryOptions));
```

The use of [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is from [Built in .NET function for unescaping characters in XML stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203485/built-in-net-function-for-unescaping-characters-in-xml-stream) .

Or perhaps you want to keep the configurations encoded as they are... then

```
XElement ndQuery = new XElement("Query", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Configuracion.QueryList));
XElement ndViewFields = new XElement("ViewFields", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Configuracion.ViewFields));
XElement ndQueryOptions = new XElement("QueryOptions", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Configuracion.QueryOptions));
```

(much shorter :-) )

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP doesn't need to actively unescape the configuration values.